# Vercel Deployment returning different api fetch than localhost (NextJS)

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13

There is a descrepency between my localhost and vercel when I deploy it. the api call is returning a html response.

Within the product.js

```
const getData = async (slug) => {
  const response = await fetch(`/../api/${slug}`,{
    headers:{
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  });
  
  
  console.log('response text: ', response.text());
  const response_two = await fetch(`/../api/${slug}`,{
    headers:{
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const {metaData, content} = await response_two.json();
  console.log("metaData:", metaData);

  return {
    slug,
    metaData,
    content,
  };
}
```

in my exported function, Page()

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPostsData = async () => {
      const slugs = await getPostMetadata();
      const postDataArray = [];

      for (const slug of slugs) {
        const postData = await getData(slug);
        postDataArray.push(postData);
      }

      setPostsData(postDataArray);
    };
```

In the [slug] route.js, the api i am fetching.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import matter from 'gray-matter';

export async function GET(request, {params}) {
    const slug = params.slug;  
    const folder = path.join(process.cwd(), 'products');
    const file = path.join(folder, `${slug}.md`);
    const content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');

    const { data, content: markdownContent } = matter(content);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({
      metaData: data,
      content: markdownContent,
    }, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }));
}
```

It is properly calling this function, from looking at the Network tab

This api call works in localhost:3000 when i use NextJS's npm run dev, however when I deploy to vercel, there is a difference in the response. The localhost text is the proper format, however in the deployment it gives a

'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON'

in console. the response txt starts with <html id="**next_error**">. When building to my localhost, the function works as well.